# array_filter to check for conditions?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-filter

Can i use array_filter to check for specific conditions in a multidimensional array to replace an if() statement?

Want it to replace something like this:

```
if($item[0] == $key && $item[1] == "Test"){
    //do something here....
}else{
    //some other code here...
}
```

Current Array:

```
Array
(
    [Zone] => Array
        (
            [Type] => s45
            [packageA1] => Array
                (
                    [level] => REMOVE FROM DB
                    [stage] => REMOVE FROM DB
                    [description] => description goes here
                    [image] => NULL
                )

        )
)
```

I want to search FIRST to see if [Type] exists. If it DOESN'T exist then i think ill use array_splice to insert it into the existing array. If it DOES exist then ill check if [packageA1] exists, if [packageA1] DOESN'T exist then i'll use array_splice once again. If [packageA1] DOES exist then ill skip over any type if inserting..

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_filter` is designed for filtering arrays, not replacing boolean logic based on the contents of arrays.

`array_filter` takes 2 parameters - `input` and `callback`.

The `callback` function should take a single parameter (an item from the array) and return either `true` or `false`. The function returns an array with all of the items which returned `false` removed.

(If no `callback` function is specified, all items equal to `false` will be removed from the resulting array.)

**Edit:**

Based on your updated text, the below code should do what you want:

```
if (!$item['Zone']['Type']) {
    $item['Zone']['Type'] = $something;
}
if (!$item['Zone']['packageA1']) {
    !$item['Zone']['packageA1'] = $something;
}
```

Obviously you need to replace `$something` with what you actually want to add.

This code could be shortened by the use of ternary operators.

If you are running PHP 5.3 or greater you can do the following:

```
$item['Zone']['Type'] = $item['Zone']['Type'] ?: $something;
$item['Zone']['packageA1'] = $item['Zone']['packageA1'] ?: $something;
```

Prior to 5.3 you cannot miss out the middle of a ternary operation and have to use the full format as follows:

```
$value = conditon ? if_true : if_false;
```

(When using `?:` as in my example, 'condition' and 'if_true' take the same value.)

The full ternary operator (for PHP prior to 5.3) would look like:

```
$item['Zone']['packageA1'] = $item['Zone']['packageA1'] ? $item['Zone']['packageA1'] : $something;
```

Comment: So is there a good way to look for nested array values so i can base actions off of and perform specific code?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. If you are checking one item over and over again you could consider a `switch` statement. If you are looking for a specific item in an array you can use `in_array`. It depends what you are doing.

Comment: I was trying to use the above code but to search for $item[0] and $item[1] inside a multidimensional array but it seems to keep failing.  I was also trying to search by array_key_exists but i wasnt having any luck..

Comment: Please update your question to include the structure of your array and what you are trying to check for. You can use `print_r($item);` to output the array.

Comment: Updated OP, Thanks for your help so far

Comment: OK your solution works! Only thing i see is that if i try to use `if (!$item['Zone']['packageA1'])` then the statement is run but i get error of an undefined index. The index of course being    `['packageA1']`

Any way to suppress the error??